# When ever I try to compile the contract I keep getting a error on this line

Tags: solidity

In remix this line gives me a error "ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier"

```
function setIsPublicMintEnabled(bool is PublicMintEnabled_) external onlyOwner {
        isPublicMintEnabled=isPublicMintEnabled;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an syntax error around `is` keyword. Refactor your function in following way:

```
function setIsPublicMintEnabled(bool isPublicMintEnabled_) external onlyOwner {
    isPublicMintEnabled = isPublicMintEnabled_;
}
```

`is` keyword is used when contract inheritance is being defined. [Here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/contracts.html#inheritance) is an detailed explanation how to use inheritance and the `is` keyword in practice.

Comment: I'm still having the same issue even with doing that

Comment: Add more context like whole contract

Comment: // SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.4; 

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol';

Comment: contract AkaysHeadNFT is ERC721, Ownable {
    uint256 public mintPrice;
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    uint256 public maxSupply;
    uint256 public maxPerWallet;
    bool public isPublicMintEnabled;
    string internal baseTokenUri;
    address payable public withdrawwallet;
    mapping (address => uint256) public walletMints;
   
    constructor() payable ERC721 ('AkaysHeadNFT' , 'AK') {
    mintPrice = 0.005 ether;
    totalSupply = 0;
    maxSupply = 10000;
    maxPerWallet = 3
   
    ;

Comment: function setIsPublicMintEnabled(bool isPublicMintEnabled_) external onlyOwner {
    isPublicMintEnabled = isPublicMintEnabled_;
 }

    function setBaseTokenUri(string calldata baseTokenUri) external onlyOwner {
        baseTokenUri = baseTokenUri;
        }

        
        function tokenURI (uint256 tokenId) public view override returns (string memory) {
            require(exists(tokenId),'Token does not exist!');
            return string(bi .encodePacked (baseTokenUri, Strings.toString(tokenId), ".json"));
            }

Comment: function withdraw() external onlyOwner {
                (bool success, ) = withdrawwallet.call{ value: address(this).balance }('');
                require (success,'withdraw failed');
                }

Comment: function mint(uint256 quantity) public payable {
    require(isPublicMintEnabled,'minting not enabled' );
   require (msg.value == quantity * mintPrice,'wrong mint value');
   require(totalSupply + quantity <= maxSupply,'sold out');
   require(walletMints[msg.sender] + quantity_ <= maxPerWallet, exceed max wallet');

   
 for (uint256 i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
    uint256 newTokenId = totalSupply + 1;
     totalSupply++;
      _safeMint (msg.sender, newTokenId);
      }
  }
}

Comment: @remixbuster67 seriously?? Please modify original post